# How to create admin tabs

Tags: wp-admin, tabs, user-interface

What I am trying to achieve is the following tab setup as in the "CoursePress" plugin for WordPress. My idea is to have different tabs for a custom post type, where the main setup tab also has the publish/schedule metabox.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

These tabs don't come from WordPress - it's not part of WP GUI.

So if you want to achieve that look, you'll have to implement it by yourself using custom HTML, implementing most of the logic and using [`add_menu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/).

**But**... **It isn't a good idea**.

First of all, interface should be consistent. All WP users know how to use native WP editors, and no one is familiar with your idea - it will be inconsistent ;)

Another reason not to implement this design is... Gutenberg - it will be default editor in WP soon and it will cause some major changes in editor layout - so most probably your idea will cause many problems then.

Comment: What do you suggest? More metaboxes? For example in CoursePress, a course has units and students, that can be edited in one page. I do not want to navigate in 10 different pages to manage one course..

Comment: It depends... But I would definitely use native WP GUI...

Comment: Yeah but wp gui suggests nothing useful for this problem / topic...

Comment: You have different post types, taxonomies and meta boxes - use them to achieve what you want. Don't invent something different - it won't be easier... There's really nothing more annoying than authors of plugins who want to reinvent all the GUI and implement their ideas inside of WP... Such interfaces are always messy, inconsistent and (most of the time) very unsecure and causing many compatibility problems...

Comment: Yeah but I want to have a course which has lectures and students. I want to navigate and manage all of this as easy as possible in one page. I see 3 custom post types, but how do I connect them? I do not want to reinvent nothing....